# Can i block the inbuild features in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to know that can Alexa train to listen only Custom created Skill ?

If yes can anyone tell me the procedure to do it.

I am into an project which basically includes Alexa into it, i want to block all the in build  commands like "Alexa, Play a song", "Alexa, Play Sounds" and etc, i only want that Alexa should only listen to my custom skill rest all commands should be ignored. In the same way any other user should not add any Skill in Alexa.

Sir Please do help me in it, 
It would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Alexa should ignore all that stuff when it uses your invocation name. For example if your invocation is cool music, when the user says alexa ask cool music to play a song it would ignore in built commands and follow the commands programmed by you.